# Nginx with Angular and suburl for Symfony

Tags: php, angular, symfony, nginx, configuration

I'm trying to make a Nginx configuration where I can have Angular and Symfony both on the same domain but the Symfony on suburl.

The issue is that I'm getting all the time 404 Not Found for the Symfony Config.

My website has a default redirection for the Login and I'm being redirect to the url but after I'm getting the 404. (test.com/api/connect/azure) is the URL I'm being redirected to.

> 2022/01/10 15:16:15 [error] 23#23: *3 open()
> "/var/www/angular/back/public/connect/azure" failed (2: No such file
> or directory)

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
    
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/test_com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/test_com.pem.com.key;
    
        server_name test.com;
    
        root /var/www/angular/front/dist;
    
        location /api {
            alias /var/www/angular/back/public;
            index index.php
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    
            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass php8:9000;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
                # current version of your application, you should pass the real
                # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
                # FPM.
                # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
                # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
                # for more information).
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
                # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
                # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
                internal;
            }
        }
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    
        error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
    }
```

Comment: Your main error is that `try_files` last parameter treated as a new URI, so it should be `try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;`. Moreover, there is a long-standing [bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) using `alias` and `try_files` directives together. Are you sure there are any static non-PHP files that should be available under `/api/` prefix? Maybe all the requests for the `/api/...` should be processed by `index.php`? Or there are several PHP scripts that should be available under `/api/` prefix?

Comment: Yes all the request for /api/ should be processed by Index.php
They are not other PHP scripts except the Index.php that should be called
I added the try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args; But I'm still having the same issue

Answer (score -2):

You have nested your location directives. I also see that you are listening on port 443 but there is no mention of which domain request nginx should respond to.

Consider using subdomains to host the Angular and Symfony applications as follows
angularapp.mydomain.com
symfonyapi.mydomain.com

You should separate the configuration for Angular and Symfony into seprate .conf files.

Comment: Hello, Due to company issue I cannot have subdomain, that's why I was trying like that but if it's not possible at all. I will just use 2 different domains.

Comment: There is no problem to use nested location blocks. There is no need to use separate domains. Splitting configuration into several `.conf` files gives you nothing but a worse config readability.